# context ctx.Done not being executed even though context was passed to the function in golang

Tags: go

I just don't understand why ctx.Done() is not being executed even though I am passing context and calling the cancel from the main? What am I doing wrong here?

```
var c = make(chan string)

func A(ctx context.Context) {
 for {
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("killing AAAA")
        return // kill A at least
    default:
        fmt.Println("in A1.. .. again")
        c <- "yesss"
    }
 }
}

//func B(ctx context.Context) {

func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    fmt.Println("BEFORE Number of active goroutines ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
    go A(ctx)
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    valueReceived := <-c
    cancel()
    fmt.Println("AFTER Number of active goroutines ", runtime.NumGoroutine())
}
```

Comment: BTW, your last question (which you deleted before I could comment), might be on topic for [codereview.se], but you should check [their help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) first to make sure. You should also be aware that deleting downvoted questions can eventually lead to [a question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271542/215552).

Comment: did not know.. ok thank you.  I will look at your links.

Comment: I guess I took it down cause I simply did not understand why asking for code review w/ the real code was getting 2 negavtive points? I just don't understand the logic behind that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The goroutine executes the default branch twice and blocks on send to `c`.  The `<-ctx.Done()` case is not executed because the goroutine is stuck in the default branch.

Fix the problem by sending from the select case instead of the branch statements.

```
func A(ctx context.Context) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("killing AAAA")
            return // kill A at least
        case c <- "yesss":
            fmt.Println("in A1.. .. again")
        }
    }
}
```

You may not see the the `killing AAAA` with this change alone because the program can exit before the goroutine runs to completion.

Wait for the goroutine to complete to see the message:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func A(ctx context.Context) {
    defer wg.Done()
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("killing AAAA")
            return // kill A at least
        case c <- "yesss":
            fmt.Println("in A1.. .. again")
        }
    }
}

...

wg.Add(1)
go A(ctx)
time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
valueReceived := <-c
cancel()
wg.Wait()
```

[Run it on the Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UQgQepaR-Lb).

Comment: I tried it and got deadlock.. looking more carefully now

Comment: it did work(I didn't change the default statement.. but I don't understand (besides adding wg... I don't know why changing default to case c<- made it work?

Comment: SO, this statement, blocks it?    default:
        fmt.Println("in A1.. .. again")
        c <- "yesss"
    }

Comment: The goroutine executes the default branch twice and blocks on send to `c`.  The `<-ctx.Done()` case is not executed because the goroutine is stuck in the default branch.

Comment: thought it would be
1)default runs and sends "yesss" to channel c

2)valueReived variable gets assigned "yesss" from c channel

3)cancel is executed which causes  ctx.Done() to be executed

4)number of go routines are printed

Comment: Insert this step between (1) and (2): default runs a second time and blocks forever on send to channel c.  The ctx.Done() case is not executed because the goroutine is blocked.

Comment: Thank you and I have accepted your answer because it helped me get through this but I still do not understand due to my fault. I just don't get why cancel() seem to be running? because next line was printed.. and if so, what did cancel() exactly do?

Comment: `cancel()` closes the channel returned by `ctx->Done()`.   That part is working. The problem is that the goroutine does not receive on the `ctx->Done()` channel because the goroutine is stuck in the default case of the select.  The call to `cancel()` does not force goroutine to jump from the receive on `c` to the the receive on `ctx->Done()`.   The goroutine needs to get there on it's own.

Comment: @hanabbs: The sequence of events that leads to your bug is: 1. The first `c <- "yesss"` finishes (`valueReceived := <-c` either finishes later, or it finishes first but then the main goroutine happens to get suspended). 2. The next loop iteration happens, and the `select` is evaluated. `cancel()` hasn't been called yet, so `ctx.Done()` returns a channel from which nothing can be received yet, and since there is a `default` clause, it is selected *without* waiting for the "cancellation signal". 3. The body of the `default` clause hangs on `c <- "yesss"` because no corresponding receive happens.

Comment: @hanabbs: 4. `cancel()` happens and closes the cancellation channel (this is the "cancellation signal"). Cool, but no one is receiving that: the `select` _previously_ checked `ctx.Done()`, but because of the `default` clause, it didn't wait for anything to happen on that channel, and now it's hanging on the second send (since it's an unbuffered channel and no one is trying to receive again).

Comment: @hanabbs: Cerise's solution solves your problem because it replaces the `default` clause with another `case`, which completely changes the behavior of `select`: when there is no `default` clause, `select` _will_ wait until something happens on one of the channels. It will only continue when `cancel()` is called (which will close the channel returned by `ctx.Done()`, causing that clause to be selected) or when another `<-c` happens (which enables the `c <- "yesss"` send to happen, causing that clause to be selected).